# How to use IAdaptable class to create working sets? [Eclipse Plug-In]

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm working on an Eclipse Plug-In which should automatically create a working set, adding projects by using their paths. I have troubles understanding how the IAdaptable class works.

```
public static void createWorkingSet(List<Path> projectPaths, String workingSetName){

    IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
    IWorkingSet newSet = manager.createWorkingSet(workingSetName, new IAdaptable[0]);
    manager.addWorkingSet(newSet);

}
```

The List given as parameter contains paths like:

`Path p = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Me", "workspace", "ProjectName");`

The way the code is written now, it only generates an empty working set, because I call the createWorkingSet method with "new IAdaptable[0]". How can I fill up an IAdaptable array to store information about the projects I want to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createWorkingSet` method requires that the objects you pass in the `elements` argument implement the `IAdaptable` interface.

If you are trying to pass Eclipse workspace projects to `createWorkingSet` you almost certain need to use the Eclipse `IProject` class which does implement `IAdaptable`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why `import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;` cannot be resolved?

Comment: You need `org.eclipse.core.resources` in your plug-in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to implement what I wanted. I add a project the following way: `IProject p = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("ProjectName");`. What methods can I use to add projects that are not in my Workspace, but I have their full Path? I've been looking everywhere but I still can't figure out.

Comment: Projects must be in the workspace. You can create a project which specifies that the actual location of the project is outside of the workspace - but that still requires creating an IProject.

Comment: I understand that, but I just don't know how to rewrite that line so I can give the full path of the project, instead of the name of a project that has to be located in my workspace.

Comment: You can't. You have to use `IProject.create` with the correct project description to create the linked project.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `projectPaths` to the method `createWorkingSet` like :

`manager.createWorkingSet( workingSetName, projectPaths.toArray( new IAdaptable[projectPaths.size()] );`

**But** because your projectPaths are not `IAdaptable`s it won't work. So you should create your own wrapper class that implements `IAdaptable` and use that to create a working set. Example code below :

```
    AdaptablePath p1 = new AdaptablePath( Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Me", "workspace", "ProjectName") );
    AdaptablePath p2 = new AdaptablePath( Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Me", "workspace", "ProjectName2") );


    List<AdaptablePath> paths = new ArrayList<AdaptablePath>();
    paths.add(p1);
    paths.add(p2);
    public static void createWorkingSet(List<AdaptablePath> paths, String workingSetName)
    {


        IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();

        IWorkingSet newSet = manager.createWorkingSet(workingSetName, paths.toArray( new IAdaptable[paths.size()] ) );
        manager.addWorkingSet(newSet);

        printElements( newSet );

    }

   private static void printElements( IWorkingSet set )
   { 
      IAdaptable[] elements = set.getElements();

        if ( elements != null && elements.length > 0 )
        {
            for ( IAdaptable element : elements )
            {
                Path p = (Path)element.getAdapter(Path.class);
                if ( p != null )
                {
                    System.out.println(p.getFileName());
                }

            }
        }
    }

    static class AdaptablePath implements IAdaptable
    {
        private Path path;
        public AdaptablePath( Path p )
        {
            this.path = p;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) 
        {
            if( adapter == Path.class )
            {
                return path;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Actually it's a List<Path>. Can I convert `Path` to `IAdaptable` somehow, to change the parameter to `List<IAdaptable>`? Or make an `IAdaptable` array/list inside the method, using my list of paths? I would prefer keeping the parameter `List<Path>`.

Comment: `Path` doesn't implement `IAdaptable` so you will get an error when you call `toArray` like this (`ArrayStoreException` to be exact).

Comment: @ERX95  The object `Path` won't work because it is not an `IAdaptable`. Instead you need to create a wrapper class that implements `IAdaptable`. I edited answer that shows how to create an adaptable path to create working set.

Comment: I edited as you said, but it still doesn't work. I get error if I make static AdaptablePath class. I switched to public and I get NullPointerException.

Comment: What error do you get for static class AdaptablePath ? and what is stack trace for nullpointerexception

Comment: "Illegal modifier for the class AdaptablePath; only public, abstract & final are permitted". After I switch to public, I get: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:379)
 at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$4(SetupUIPlugin.java:350)
 at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)`

Comment: And also warning at getAdapter method: `Multiple markers at this line
 - implements org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable.getAdapter
 - Type safety: The return type Object for getAdapter(Class) from the type AdaptablePath needs 
  unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type IAdaptable
 - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized`

Comment: I don't know where you are creating the adaptablepath class. The `AdaptablePath` needs to be a inner class outside of the method. The NullPointerException you see has nothing to do with this class. It is somehow related to oomph setup. A [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489772) points to something you may find interesting.